# Does Python have a string function to find a section of a string

Tags: python

I'm trying to filter some log files that are in the format of a table/dataset but `.endswith()` and `.startswith()` are not meeting my requirments. I'm using an anonymous function but need to adapt my Python code to check if a string contains .jpg

```
logfilejpg = sc.textFile("/loudacre/logs/*.log").filter(lambda line: line.endswith('.jpg'))
```

Comment: Use `in` → ex: `".jpg" in string`?

Comment: Yes imagine it it part of a dataset or table

Comment: What is your question .. what you have tried.. where are the samples?

Comment: @user1554264 there is no metion of a dataset or table in your question. Please update it if neccessary

Comment: Updated to give more context.

Comment: so `logfilejpg` is a list of strings?

Comment: Yes it is, that have been loaded into Apache Spark

Comment: Does the edit to my answer help you?

Comment: Yes it does thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `in`:

```
'.jpg' in 'something.jpg foo'
Out: True
```

You can also put it in your lambda expression:

```
lambda line: '.jpg' in line
```

Example:

```
list(filter(lambda line: '.jpg' in line, ["foo", "foo.jpg.bar", "bar.jpg"]))
Out: ['foo.jpg.bar', 'bar.jpg']
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the index of where the ".jpg" starts at:

```
hello = "world.jpg"

print(hello.find(".jpg"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the inintial string by " " (space) then by "." and take the second value in the resulting array. Of course it depends on how your initial string is. The basic idea is you can isolate the ".jpg" and use equal to check.

To verify that the file is actually a jog, you can try to open it. If it fails, the file is ether other format or corrupt, see also the excepption you get.

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.find()` and `len()`, you could find the substring like so:

```
a_string = 'there is a .jpg here.'
start = a_string.find('.jpg') # The lowest index in a_string where '.jpg' is found
end = start + len('.jpg')

print(a_string[start:end])
# .jpg
```